# R Temporary Directory Set to External Drive

Tags: r

When running the RecordLinkage package in R on a large dataset, the GUI failed and closed down.

I realize now that as a result of R's activity, 120GB of data had been stored in my Windows Temporary folder (file format `.ff`), running into the existing limits of my HD.

I would like to plug into an external drive with more space, and set the temporary directory for R to use there.

Can I do this in R, before running my analysis?  What is the command?

Is there another way around this problem I'm not thinking about?  Thanks kindly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are generating *.ff files, you appear to making use of the `ff` package.

Assuming this to be true, you should be able to set the `fftempdir` option as follows...

```
...
library(ff)
options("fftempdir"="/EnterYourFilePathHere/"...)
...
```

Just replace `EnterYourFilePathHere` with a path to your external hdd.

You should read more about the `ff` package and the `fftempdir` in the package documentation: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html

The package handles the temp files differently (e.g. deletion, etc.) depending on whether or not it takes `fftempdir` from your working directory (i.e. `getwd()`) or from the `fftempdir` option.