# How to fix save.ffdf on remote server

Tags: r, memory-management, matrix, bigdata, ffbase

I can't `save.ffdf` or `move.ffdf`. Also, the deprecated `ffdfsave` is broken.

```
require(ff);require(ffbase)
x <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5*5),ncol=5))
x <- as.ffdf(x)
save.ffdf(x,getwd())
```

I will get the following error:

`Error in`filename<-.ff`(`*tmp*`, value = "/home/... Deleted .../path$X0.0.ff") : 
  ff file rename from '/tmp/RtmpasUciV/ffdf346c5f0daaea.ff' to '/home/... Deleted .../path$X0.0.ff' failed`

The only thing that will work is:

```
require(ff);require(ffbase)
x <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5*5),ncol=5))
x <- as.ffdf(x)
save.ffdf(x,tempfile())
```

Note that when I call this on my local terminal it works. It's just when I try this on a remote server it does not work.

I will also get the error underneath the above error:

```
In addition: Warning message:
In file.rename(oldnam, value) :
cannot rename file '/tmp/RtmpasUciV/ffdf346c5f0daaea.ff' to '/home/... Deleted .../path$X0.0.ff', reason 'Invalid cross-device link'
```

Comment: for issues related to save.ffdf, do report on [https://github.com/edwindj/ffbase/issues](https://github.com/edwindj/ffbase/issues), for the issue on your remote server, you need to provide more information on the hardware of your tmp directory and your home directory as this is where you requested ff to store your files. These 2 folders don't seem to be on the same filesystem.

Comment: @jwijffels The problem is that it auto saves onto `tmp`. How can I get it to first save in the directory of my choosing instead of having to move from `tmp`? For example saving `ffsave` with `ff_matrix` will work, don't see why `ffdf` saving can't do the same.

Comment: search on stackoverflow for options and fftempdir or look at the documentation of ?ff section 'ff options'. E.g. solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687041/r-temporary-directory-set-to-external-drive

Comment: @jwijffels This will save the `name$colname1.ff` files but won't save the `RData` file, hence doesn't really solve.

Comment: Please report at https://github.com/edwindj/ffbase/issues

Comment: @jwijffels A separate issue. The files get deleted when I close my R session!

Comment: It is a feature of the /tmp directory which is deleted when you close R. You need to save your files in another directory.

Comment: @jwijffels How do I save these files into another directory? I have been spending all day trying to fix this issue.